# How do I get the index of an appended object in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$("input").keypress(function(e){
    let value = $("input").val()
    if(e.which == 13 && value != ""){
        $("input").val("")
        $(".itemCategRow:nth-child(1)").append("<div class=\"button\">" + value + "</div>")
    }
})

$(".button").clicked(function(){
    alert($(this).index())
})
```

nothing happens when I click the buttons, the reason for getting their certain indexes is to
remove certain buttons.

Comment: It's `$('.button').click()` not `.clicked()`

Comment: still didn't work :(

Comment: You mean `$(".button").click(function(){  alert($(this).index()) })` didn't work?

Comment: logically it is correct but the alert is still click the button I appended

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the button is added dynamically, you can only listen to events on it through *"event delegation"*. Try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(){
    alert($(this).index())
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! YOU ARE A GOD @ruleboy21

Comment: last question please :(.... what if i want it to be a right click instead of left

Comment: Then you will have to use `contextmenu` instead of `click`.

Comment: freakin legend! CHEERS BRO!